# What is the opposite of "on drugs"?

Tags: single-word-requests

When someone is *not under the influence of alcohol*, you call them *sober*. Is there a similar word for *not under the influence of mind-altering drugs*?

An example usage would be:

> I am one of the few who listens to Radiohead or Dave Matthews while ________.

Comment: In addition to [what Matt said](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/147159/5438), _clean_ is a bit ambiguous; it could also mean that you are freshly showered while listening to the music. When you say _sober_, everyone knows you are talking about alcohol.

Comment: No they don't. There are many instances where _sober_ equates to solemn or level-headed.

Comment: In this sentence, "clean" could be ambiguous. However, more generally, if a drugs context has been mentioned, "clean" will be clear. Alternatively, if you use a phrase like "I've been clean for 3 months" it would be clear that you weren't talking about being washed.

Comment: @starsplusplus Unless you are a hippy, in which case either use of the phrase "clean for 3 months" would be a feat.

Comment: ...(it doesn't answer the question, but) while it was 1994.  Can't you youths expand a bit?

Comment: ***Sober*** is almost exclusively reserved for *not under the influence of **alcohol***. I'd say ***unintoxicated*** is a more generic way of saying *not under the influence of **any psychoactive substance*** (alcohol, prescribed / recreational drugs, or anything else that might affect normal brain function).

Comment: Um, maybe off drugs?

Answer (score 8):

The obvious answer is "not high".

mplungjan suggests *clean*, but that would imply that you have given up drugs, not just that you aren't high at the moment.

If you used *sober* that would be fine, because if someone is sober, then they are not high. Dictionary definitions suggest that *sober* is only used with alcohol, but I think extending it to other drugs makes sense.

Comment: Not all drugs make you high.

Comment: @starsplusplus But in this case I did ask specifically about "mind altering drugs".

Comment: @IQAndreas Right, but not all "mind-altering drugs" make you *high*.

Comment: I disagree with your statement that being _clean_ means you have given up on drugs completely; often, people say that they are "clean at the moment" and the like, which shows it can be used for a specific time.

Answer (score 6):

[Straight](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=straight) used to be an answer to this question, but the 70s-90s are gone, and the language has moved on.

Comment: Straight also refers to never having smoked if I remember right

Comment: @mplungjan: Yes, but not always to the exclusion of those who merely not currently taking drugs.

Comment: I still hear it used to mean "not on drugs at the moment" today. It does have other meanings though, so context is important.

Comment: We used to use the phrase 'straight, sane and sober' in that sort of context . . .but that would be about 1971 . . .

Comment: This sounds like the best fit to the example sentence in the question.

Answer (score 4):

I first suggested *Clean* but I would think the most attractive, all compassing would be

> I am one of the few who listens to Radiohead or Dave Matthews while not under the influence.

That would not focus on drugs alone but would definitely include them

Comment: Honestly I would take that to mean "under the influence of alcohol" unless it was specifically clarified, or some clearer context was given from the sentence before or something.

Comment: "Not on drugs" is shorter and less euphemistic ;)

Comment: Post as answer and I will vote it up

Answer (score 3):

"Clean" is fairly widely understood, but you need to have a specific context indicating drugs somehow otherwise it would be understood to mean "not dirty". In the sentence you gave, without any other context it would mean "not dirty".

There are a range of other answers given here, but I think that they're all less clear/longer/more ambiguous than simply "**not on drugs**".

> I am one of the few who listens to Radiohead or Dave Matthews while not on drugs.

Answer (score 3):

'Sober' is used in drug detox communities unrelated to alcohol. In common parlance it refers to 'not drunk' but its meaning is definitely applicable to other contexts.

'Clean' in a drug context generally implies that the person who's clean has quit the drug permanently. You could say you've been 'clean for two hours' but only as a joke.

If you've just come down from a drug high, you could say you're 'sober', but not 'clean'.

Comment: *Not under the influence* does not mean that you are *clean*, merely; currently sober. +1 for explaining the difference between *clean* and *sober*; the reason there is a saying "clean *and* sober".

Answer (score 2):

" . . . while unimpaired by drugs, licit and/or illicit."

Answer (score 2):

Like many others have suggested before, it's probably best and easier, to say you're **not XXX**. After all if I do not drink or take any drugs, I am like any other *normal, lucid, stone-cold sober person*.

> I am one of the few who listens to Radiohead or Dave Matthews while
>   **not**...

- **bombed** (**out of my mind**).
  [experiencing the strong effect of alcohol or illegal drugs](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/bombed?topic=drunkenness-and-sobriety)
- **tripping**.
  Slightly old fashioned perhaps, reminiscent of the 60s and 70s, but unequivocally connected to drugs.  [*When I was a student I spent a lot of time tripping out on LSD.*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/trip_7?topic=drugs-general-words)

Just realized I may have hit upon the word which fits the OP's request.

> I am one of the few who listens to Radiohead or Dave Matthews while
>   remaining **lucid**. [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/lucid?q=lucid)

Comment: Lucid also implies you aren't groggy from lack of sleep (or just general mental incapacity). It works in this context, but isn't exactly "the opposite".

Answer (score 1):

To not be under the influence is to be sober. They use it at Alcoholics Anonymous and other drug rehabilitations.