# 'Antonym' for anesthetized?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Is there a word which refers to a state for an animal or human that is **not** anesthetized (or influenced by other artificial consciousness altering substances) for an academic or professional context? I am looking for a term that would make it specifically clear that there is no influence of anesthesia rather then a more ambiguous word like "conscious" or "wakeful" (the type of words I have been able to find so far).

Comment: I would suggest looking through [this post](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147148/what-is-the-opposite-of-on-drugs)

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want to use this word? What do you need an antonym specifically? Why can't you just say "not anesthetized"?

Comment: Inazuma - Thank you but I am looking for something a little more formal and a term not specifically related to any kind of illegal (or simply mind altering) substance.

Comment: sumelic - The specific usage is probably beyond the scope here but I would like to describe conducting tests or experiments on a person/animal which has not been sedated. Although simply saying something along the lines of "not anesthetized" or "not sedated" may be the simplest answer (and one I may have to go with), I was hoping that there might be a specific word that I could use instead.

Comment: Thanks for the additional description. In fact, the more specific you can be, the better. Here are the guidelines for asking word request questions on this site: http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info By the way, to send reply messages, you'll have to use the @ symbol before somebody's name.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "[sensate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sensate)" or "[sensible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sensible)" :  having conscious awareness or rationality, capable of receiving sensory impressions

Answer (score 1):

In this context I'd recommend '[sober](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sober)'.

> not intoxicated or drunk.

Reference:
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sober

It is often associated with abstinence of alcohol though, see http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sober (*Not affected by alcohol; not drunk.*) so maybe there is a more appropriate term out there.

Answer (score 1):

In our clinical journal articles, we would state that a procedure done without anesthesia is *anesthesia free*, for example *an anesthesia-free dental procedure.* This implies that the procedure is typically done with anesthesia, but in this instance it is not.

As for the antonym for an *anesthetized patient*, it would simply be an *unanesthetized patient*.

The Merriam-Webster Medical Dictionary has this entry:

> Medical definition of *[unanesthetized:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/unanesthetized)*
>
> not having been subjected to an anesthetic -- *an unanesthetized patient*

This does not really apply to sedation, which is different than anesthesia.

Answer (score 0):

**Sensitised** sounds like the word you need.

From [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sensitize?q=sensitized&searchDictCode=all)

> Cause (someone or something) to respond to certain stimuli; make sensitive: